# Can we paint or draw imaginary or nonexistent objects?

Tags: ontology

You know, imagainary objects are concepts and nonexistent objects don't have properties. I can't imagine drawing concepts (=imaginary objects) or nonexistent objects which we can't even see.

Can we paint or draw imaginary or nonexistent objects?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149960/discussion-on-question-by-collins-can-we-paint-or-draw-imaginary-or-nonexistent); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

We can both talk about and draw what does not exist. Here's a picture of Leopold Bloom

[image]

Just because they are imaginary, does not mean we cannot imagine them. I suppose it may not *really* be Leopold Bloom, but it might meet his description!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn) you can see an image of a unicorn:

[image]

Comment: I mean, if I draw something without conciousness, and it doesn't exist, can we draw nonexistent objects (not concepts)? Like scribble, doodle, graffiti?

Answer (score 0):

Again you seem to be confusing different meanings of the word exist. You can draw or paint whatever you like, consciously imagining your subject or not (for example by throwing paint at a canvass with your eyes closed and your attention elsewhere). Your subject could be something that exists in a concrete sense, something that once existed in a concrete sense, some imagined object, a concept, any combination of the foregoing, various other types that I lack the rigour to mention, or you might have no subject that you are aware of (as in the case of the paint splats). Regardless of whether your subject ever existed before you painted it, thanks to your artistic efforts a representation of it exists as a property of your painting, and it will exist, perhaps in a variety of forms, in the minds of the astonished art-lovers who throng to see it in whichever gallery managed to scrape up the millions required to purchase it. And if you have been paying attention, you will have noticed that in the previous sentence I used the words 'it' and 'exist' to denote a range of different things in a way that is common to everyday speech and capable of being understood by most people without angst or drama.

Perhaps you might like to search for images using the keywords 'abstract art'. The ensuing results should give you plenty of food for thought.

Comment: Always thank you... I'm actually scared of Conifold, so I hesitated to post this question. Again thank you.

Comment: I think it would be an interesting experiment for you to create an abstract drawing of @conifold and post it here as the subject of a question. I find it hard to believe that conifold is not a committee of at least ten specialists in different fields.